# Two directives with same input binding

Tags: angular

I have two directives with the same property binding, resulting in a name conflict.

```
<p appBorder color="red" appBackground color="yellow">Hello World!</p>
```

In this case, border and background are both yellow.

Of course, I can rename one of the Input() bindings. But in a large project with many independent programmers or bringing together code from different projects, this does not seem ideal. Is there a way to specify, which property belongs to which directive? E.g. `appborder.color="red`.

Comment: is color the only input for these directives?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass values to attribute directive directly

```html
<p [appBorder]="'red'" [appBackground]="'yellow'">Hello World!</p>
```

to do this you will have to add an input decorator in the directives with the same name as the directive

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appBorder]',
})
export class BorderDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() set appBorder(color: string) {
    this.color = color
  }
  @Input() private color: string = '';
  ...
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[appBackground]',
})
export class BackgroundDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() set appBackground(color: string) {
    this.color = color
  }
  @Input() private color: string = '';
  ...
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#passing-values-into-an-attribute-directive

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know. My assumption is that the direct attribute is already used for some other purpose, e.g. border width or so.

Comment: Directives do not support namespaces, probably the only option is to rename or add extra inputs @Input() private bgcolor: string = ''; and @Input() private bordercolor: string = '';

Comment: Thank you Stash. Come as a surprise to me. But be it so.